# Wordpress pagination links empty on custom post type query

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

I've visited a number of previous entries and didn't find the solution still. Others have the same problem but their findings weren't applicable to this case. So I'm hoping someone can give me a hint with this issue. :(

So I have a custom query and already added in the paged argument:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$snapshotargs=array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_type' => 'qd_galleries',
    'qd_galleries_cat' => 'snapshot',
    'paged' => $paged
);

$snapshotposts = new WP_Query( $snapshotargs);
```

Then, between closing the loop's while and if (as stated in the codex), I placed the navigation links and reset the query:

```
<?php } ?><!-- end while -->
    <nav id="page_nav">
        <?php get_previous_posts_link('More »') ?><br/>
        <?php get_next_posts_link('More »') ?>
    </nav>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php }; ?><!-- end if -->
```

I even tried with [next_posts_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) instead of [get_next_posts_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_posts_link).

**Both of them return blank, empty page_nav div, even though there are almost 150 posts to show and pagination is set to 10.**

What could the problem be? Am I missing something?

Thank you in advanced for your support!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full functional code you can modify to fit your needs:

```
// Note that on your site's blog page the query var is page, not paged
// everywhere else it is paged 
$curpage = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$snapshotargs=array(
'posts_per_page' => 10,
'post_type' => 'qd_galleries',
'qd_galleries_cat' => 'snapshot',
'paged' => $curpage
);

query_posts($snapshotargs);
$pagecount = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

while(have_posts()):the_post();?>
    <h1><a href='<?php the_permalink();?>'><?php the_title();?></a></h1>
    <p> the_excerpt();?></p>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

// Note that the pagination is outside of the loop
  <p class='pagination-links'>
   Showing page <?=$curpage;?> of <?=$pagecount;?>&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <?php previous_posts_link();?>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= ($curpage > 1 && $curpage != $pagecount)?'|':'';?>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php next_posts_link(); ?>
    </p>
```

Comment: I see you added in the $pagecount. I tried it and, although it makes all sense to me it didn't work :(. I'm stuck again. I wrote in the line: `$pagecount = $wp_query->max_num_pages;` and rewrote the nav links as you told me. Both return still empty and $pagecount is 0 (which I guess it should be on the first page). Is there something in functions.php that could be preventing pagination??? I can't imagine why this won't work :S. Thanks anyway @wunderdojo.

Comment: Than you! After adding the $pagecount, my query args, loop and nav links were exactly the same as yours. The only difference was the query itself. I was using the WP_Query method and by changing that to query_posts(), as in your example, it worked. Also I obviously had to remove the reset_postdata function so that next page wasn't still the same one (that was dumb of me). So thank you again @wunderdojo (sorry that I cannot vote your response up yet).